# Gitlab schedule jobs with `rules` are not running and can't be triggered

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I would like to run one or multiple jobs within a scheduled context and therefore used the specific rule to declare it like this.
Problem is that the pipeline will neither be triggered by my schedule configuration nor when i manually trigger it via the scheduling pipeline UI. I just don't see any triggered scheduled pipeline at all.

Gitlab Version: 12.9.2

gitlab-ci.yml (partially):

```
workflow:
rules:
    -   if: $CI_COMMIT_TAG
    -   if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH

non-scheduled-job:
...
rules:
    -   if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE != "schedule"'


scheduled-job:
...
rules:
    -   if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "schedule"'
        when: always
    -   if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE != "schedule"'
        when: never
```

I know that the second rule for the scheduling-job is not needed but even without this the pipeline is not properly running.

Comment: looks like there is an open issue to this problem: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/218374

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, as for Workflows logic, Gitlab is very twiggy.
If you use ***Workflow*** section and ***Rules*** conditions for your jobs, you have to obviously declare 'Scheduled' type of pipeline in the Workflow section to enable it in your configuration:

```
workflow:                                                 
    rules:
      - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "schedule"'
      ...
```

Or you may enable all types of pipelines in your configuration just adding at the end of ***workflow:rules***

```
workflow:                                                 
  rules:
    ...
    - when: always
```

---

In other way, use may use ***except/only*** notation for scheduled jobs and it will work, but only if your workflow conditions met:

```
only:
  - schedules
```

---

This approach may appear [merging conflicts](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/includes.html#overriding-external-template-values) if you use ***include*** option.
Because merging lets you extend and override dictionary mappings, but you cannot add or modify items to an included array. Thus you have to obviously declare all previously added ***workflow:rules*** array items in the last included YAML or use [anchors](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#anchors).

See [issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/218374#note_568717759) for details.

Answer (score -3):

You can use `only`.

E.g.

```
scheduled-job:
  only:
    - schedules
```

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/schedules.html

But, when reusing the snippet in other jobs,
do not use rules togetther with `only` / `except`.